# Kaiki Deishu and Tooe Gaen Relationship

Tags: monogatari-series

What is the relationship of Kaiki Deishu and Tooe Gaen?

Why Kaiki Deishu decide to help to deceive Nadeko for the sake of Tooe Gaen's child, Suruga Kanbaru?

Kaiki Deishu also treat Suruga Kanbaru nicely and show warm concern toward her, what make Kaiki Deishu show such concern?

Answer (score 3):

To your 1st and 3rd question. Tooe Gaen and Kaiki were both in the same Occult Research Club in college. Later on, Kaiki was revealed to have feelings for Tooe Gaen, and has made a promise to keep her daughter, Kanbaru, safe - [Source](https://bakemonogatari.fandom.com/wiki/Deishuu_Kaiki#Background)

To answer your 2nd question, he helped deceive Nadeko because it would indirectly help Kanbaru. If Araragi was killed by Nadeko in that arc, it would:

1. Make Kabaru sad
2. Cause Kiss-Shot to regain her full strength and eventually destroy the town, killing everyone, including Kanbaru.